# error on feuser edit: is not integer

Tags: typo3

I extend feuser with custom fields. All work good. If I type integer value it was save good. But if I type string value I get error - 1332933658: "" is no integer.  You can see this on the follow screenshots.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ3Tl.png)

[image]

ext_tables.php

```
#
# Table structure for table 'fe_users'
#
CREATE TABLE fe_users (
        aboutmyself varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    aboutmypartner varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_extbase_type varchar(255) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

Model:

```
<?php
namespace Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model;

/***************************************************************
 *
 *  Copyright notice
 *
 *  (c) 2017
 *
 *  All rights reserved
 *
 *  This script is part of the TYPO3 project. The TYPO3 project is
 *  free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  The GNU General Public License can be found at
 *  http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
 *
 *  This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  This copyright notice MUST APPEAR in all copies of the script!
 ***************************************************************/

/**
 * User
 */
class User extends \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User
{

    /**
     * aboutmyself
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $aboutmyself = '';

    /**
     * aboutmypartner
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $aboutmypartner = '';


    /**
     * Returns the aboutmyself
     *
     * @return int $aboutmyself
     */
    public function getAboutmyself()
    {
        return (string)$this->aboutmyself;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the aboutmypartner
     *
     * @return int $aboutmypartner
     */
    public function getAboutmypartner()
    {
        return (string)$this->aboutmypartner;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the aboutmyself
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAboutmyself($aboutmyself)
    {
        $this->aboutmyself = (string)$aboutmyself;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the aboutmypartner
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAboutmypartner($aboutmypartner)
    {
        $this->aboutmypartner = (string)$aboutmypartner;
    }







    /**
     * __construct
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initStorageObjects();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
     * Do not modify this method!
     * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
     * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initStorageObjects()
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: What's the type of the db field you added? Could you add some code to illustrate what you did to extend feuser?

Comment: ext_tables.php

#
# Table structure for table 'fe_users'
#
CREATE TABLE fe_users (
        aboutmyself varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 aboutmypartner varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 tx_extbase_type varchar(255) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type hint for your fields aboutmyself and aboutmypartner is defined as

```
@var int
```

but you store a VARCHAR. Try changing the hint to

```
@var string
```

and clear all caches (also, emptying the typo3temp folder can't hurt).